# Cordova AppRate Plugin (onButtonClicked) not working

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have included the ratings plugin in my App and it works fine.

I am now trying to console.log the button that was clicked. I am not able to do the with the onButtonClicked method. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

My code is as shown below:

```
.config(['$cordovaAppRateProvider', function($cordovaAppRateProvider) {
    var onButtonClicked = function(buttonIndex) {
      console.log("onButtonClicked -> " + buttonIndex);
    };

    var prefs = {
      language: 'en',
      appName: 'AppName',
      iosURL: 'AppURL',
      promptAgainForEachNewVersion: true,
      usesUntilPrompt:1,
      callbacks: {}
    };

    prefs.callbacks.onButtonClicked = onButtonClicked;

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
      $cordovaAppRateProvider.setCustomLocale({
        title: 'Rate the App',
        message: 'Rate this App?',
        cancelButtonLabel: 'No, Thanks',
        laterButtonLabel: 'Maybe Later',
        rateButtonLabel: 'Yes',
      });

      $cordovaAppRateProvider.setPreferences(prefs);
    }, false);
 }])
```

Comment: Try from this [link](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/find-application-version-ionic-framework-app/)

Comment: Does this plugin knows the user has already rated the app and would disable the popup in the future ? Or does it repeatedly bring up the popup even after the user rated the app ?